# Clear VS 2017 cache

Tags: visual-studio, caching, memcached

I'm using `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` in my application. I'm trying to delete cache because I'm making `Unit Test` but all the data come from the cache at 8:54AM, and it's not refreshing.

So, I've tried to delete `Visual Studio's AppData folder` without success. I've also downloaded a tool to clear MEF Component Cache, without success.

I've also tried to run my test through Visual Studio 15, but it's also the same cache.

Anyone can help me on how to delete this cache ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call MemoryCache.Remove before the unit test